# Interactive Formulas In Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I write interactive equations and formulas in Mirosoft Word just like excel. For example, in excel if I change a value other related corresponding values get changed automatically.

I mean I just want to do the calculation of excel in word. Is there any way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The only built-in facility in Word for doing calculations (other than embedding a spreadsheet) is to use its formula fields. But those are *nothing like* as capable as Excel cell formulas - there is only a small set of built-in functions, formulas do not auto-update their results, Word cannot work out the correct evaluation sequence of a set of related formulas, and addressing values and cells is quite inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

Word is document/text-oriented, not so much calculation-oriented as is Excel.

Doing calculations in Word is possible but extremely awkward.
I can only see two methods for that:

- Embed an Excel partial spreadsheet inside the Word document
- Write the calculations using VBA macros.

Both methods are not easy to implement, but the first one
requires much less study.

Reference :
[Embed an Excel Worksheet in a Word Document (Easy Tutorial)](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/embed.html).